# How to configure SCSS in Oracle JET?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, scss-mixins, oracle-jet

Trying to configure SCSS in Oracle JET project.
This is my **oraclejet-serve.js** configuration.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function () {
  return {
      sass: {
        files: [
          {
            cwd:'src/scss',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: 'web/scss/*.css'
          }
        ],
        commands: ['compileSass']
      },
    web: {
    },
    hybrid: {
    }
  };
};
```

It keeps rewriting the source SCSS file as it is without preprocessing.